# Python- How to change the file name of a variable within a function

Tags: python

So basically I want to change the file name of the variable within the function after I've called it, however I'm unsure of exactly how to do this. I'm pretty sure it'll be something fairly simple, however I'm probably looking at it the wrong way. Below is a more detailed explanation of what I want to achieve:

Say I have two files, uncooked_fish and uncooked_cake:

```
def cook(food):
    food.save(food + "_XYZ.png") #the current saving method I'm using, which is not sufficient
```

After calling them within the function, I want to change their names to cooked_fish.png and finished_cake.png, however with my current saving method, I'm unable to do so. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused- if I use os.rename; would I have to have a different os.rename for each of the file names, and even so, having multiple os.rename's for one variable wouldn't work. Still very much stuck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using string slicing to remove the file extensions, which allowed me to insert additional information before then replacing the file extension, code is as follows:

```
food.save (food[0:-4]+ '_X.png')
```

Essentially, using slicing you'd be able to completely rewrite the file name, so having a similar effect to os.rename.

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @hcwhsa, you should rewrite your `cook` method as follows:

```
import os

def cook(food):
   // make something with food...
   os.rename(food, food + '.png')   // e.g.: rename 'finished_cake' to 'finished_cake.png'
```

Comment: I get the following error when I attempt to use the variable twice- WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists. Have I done something wrong...?

Comment: Ok, fixed that issue, however another still remains. If, for example I have the following os.rename(food, food + '_x.png'), I want it to display it as food_x.png, but instead in displays it as food.png_x. How do I fix this?

Comment: This is quite strange. Are u sure that you wrote `os.rename(food, food + '_x.png')`?

Comment: Yea, that's how I wrote it, so something else is happening. If I instead change the rename to os.rename(food, food + '_x') it says that it doesn't understand the file extension, .png_x. So, the rename's reading food as finished_cake.png, rather then just finished_cake. Is there any way to remove the file extension and then replace it after additional characters have been added to the filename?

Comment: You can use `os.path.splitext(path)` to split the **filepath** in root  and extension. 
More here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext